# edge animate call event on specific image section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adobe-edge

I am using edge animate 2014 and I want a mouse over event on the specific section of the image. I am not sure how can I do this.

I need a mouse over event when mouse moves on the blue section with the Athlete programs text it should call function1. When the mouse leaves that area, I want to call function2.

[image]

I have implemented the mouse move event but when the image is imported in the edge animate it creates a square box and this is causing a problem. Please see the image below.

[image: image in the adobe edge]

The mouse over works on the whole square I want to work only for the blue color section. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share your code with us? :)

Comment: Sounds like you need to master HTML's `<map>` tag - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: its simply a mouseover event on the image.Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${_AP01012}", "mouseover", function(sym, e) { function1();  });

Comment: @Roamer-1888 how to do this in wdge animate

Comment: You need to define an [area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) with `shape="poly"` - ie a polygon that approximates to the wedge shape.

Comment: You can show transparent div over the images, see :https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/. An then bind separate events on these events. These divs will have positions where you want them to work.

Comment: Here's a **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/93yk5pad/1/)**

Comment: At least, that's how you would do it with raw HTML/jQuery. I'm not sure how adobe-edge affects matters.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 how did you find coordinates?

Comment: I used an [online utility](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/s/u/summerstyle/365ccfd644f2b008c33f0046d2ba1a8f/summer-html-image-ma_1355318513_demo_package/index.html).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 thanks but i am sure how to use in edge animate. I want to this in edge animate but could not find imagemap tutorial

Comment: As far as I can tell, you need to master two things; (1) How to define a hotspot - [page 322 here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=u20JPqVa8cMC&pg=PA322&lpg=PA322&source=bl&ots=edHWLRmqRQ&sig=RPU2Iw9APXKUtVRJP1NLce1rlPE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA0I287vXJAhUCDBoKHSIEDqAQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&f=false) may help. (2) How to link Adobe Edge to javascript - [Adobe Edge Animate JavaScript API](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/edgeanimate/api/old/0.1.7/EdgeAPI.0.1.7.html) may help. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes i checked that links but it didnt help i think i will go with your solution can we also change the color from blue to black on mouseover wedge1

Comment: Image map won't in itself provide a color change but you could either swap out the image src or apply a [css filter](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/), in the mouseover/mouseout handlers.